# greek alphabet in superscript of the legend in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I want to use the alpha greek letter in the superscript in the legend of my matplotlib figure but my code cannot understand it. Could you please let me know the right way to write alpha in legend as superscript?

```
plt.legend(["Q", "$Q_{\alpha}$"]
```

Comment: According to matplotlib documenation, you should be using raw strings: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html  So, try `plt.legend(["Q", r"$Q_{\alpha}$"]`

Comment: And I suggest putting all labels into $...$ to have the same font for all labels.

Comment: Thank you so much. plt.legend(["Q", r"$Q_{\alpha}$"]) works properly =)